# Magento2: Need to get url of system configuration section fields

Tags: magento2

I Need to get a URL of system configuration section fields. 
Anyone have a solution for this?

[image]

```
Here is my code:

namespace abc\Mkt\Model\System\Message;

use Magento\Framework\Notification\MessageInterface;

/**
* Class abcKeyMessage
*/
class abcKeyMessage implements MessageInterface
{    
    protected $_objectManager;
    protected $urlBuilder;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    )
    {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }

   /**
    * Message identity
    */
   const MESSAGE_IDENTITY = 'mkt_system_message';
   /**
    * Retrieve unique system message identity
    *
    * @return string
    */
   public function getIdentity()
   {
       return self::MESSAGE_IDENTITY;
   }
   /**
    * Check whether the system message should be shown
    *
    * @return bool
    */

   /**
    * Retrieve system message text
    *
    * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
    */
   public function getText()
   {
        return __('<a href='.$this->urlBuilder->getUrl('adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/graz_auth').'>connector</a> is expired.');
   }
   /**
    * Retrieve system message severity
    * Possible default system message types:
    * - MessageInterface::SEVERITY_CRITICAL
    * - MessageInterface::SEVERITY_MAJOR
    * - MessageInterface::SEVERITY_MINOR
    * - MessageInterface::SEVERITY_NOTICE
    *
    * @return int
    */
   public function getSeverity()
   {
       return self::SEVERITY_MAJOR;
   }
}
```

Comment: adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/<section_id>

Comment: Can you share full code for this? Need to add in model file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create url using `\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface` class. Inject this below code in your construct:

```
protected $urlInterface;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface
){
$this->urlInterface = $urlInterface;
}
```

then, use this below code for create URL :

```
$this->urlInterface->getUrl('adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/yourSectionId');
```

Comment: getting issue: Type Error occurred when creating object:

Comment: Sorry. It's typo. Updated code please check it.

Comment: I already corrected with your code. But not working. Updating my question with code

Comment: Any error or system log?

Comment: yes Type Error occurred when creating object: abc\Mkt\Model\System\Message\AbcKeyMessage

Comment: Did you removed generated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102155/discussion-between-shiwani-and-rohan-hapani).

Comment: Thanks after running commands this works for me

Comment: Happy to help !! Happy coding :)